# Interventional query without adjustment set

Tags: statistical-inference, causality, causal-diagrams, do-calculus

Given the following casual graph, we need to find the formula for $P(y|do(a))$ in terms of observed variables Y, A, W, M.
[image]

My attempt is to try different back-door and front-door adjustment sets, however, I don't see any. Most likely, I need to use Pearl’s do calculus but how can I do it?

**How to solve it with Pearl’s do calculus?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer using do-calculus would be quite tedious, which is why most causal inference packages such as [do-why](https://www.pywhy.org/dowhy/v0.10.1/user_guide/index.html) abstract away from it. Since you seem to care about adjustment sets you can use graphical criteria (blocking all open backdoor paths), to see that you'd have to condition on $U_2$. The software [daggity](https://www.dagitty.net/) (and many others) has some nice tools to do perform this step automatically.